# Virtually squash commits for code review

Tags: gitlab

GitLab allows to add comments / discussions to individual commits, which is very useful e.g. to ping someone with a quick question or ask for a review:

[image]

Is there any way to get a similar view for *multiple* commits?

Something like

https://myGitlabserver/myProject/myRepo/commit/12345+6789a+bcdef+13567

(^ doesn't work...)

I guess one possible workaround would be to `git cherry-pick` those commits to a temporary branch, temporarily revert them in the master branch, and then create a merge request... nasty.

What I'm looking for is an easy way to start a comment thread on a set of changes which already *are* in the master branch. So basically, I would like GitLab to virtually, but not physically, squash those commits together just for the sake of starting a comment thread on them.

Possible?

Comment: If the commits are already merged into master, aren't they already together for review? I might not be fully understanding your intent.

Comment: I can't quite remember either. Looks like I asked this before we were on GH Enterprise.

Comment: What's the use case for commenting on something already merged? A Merge Request offers all the functionality you're looking for but is before it's merged (which generally is the desired functionality). Also, after the Merge Request is merged, it can still be opened on commented on.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't remember what I had in mind four years ago. :) I'll close the question.